# Pass username and other data to socket.io connection

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I'm wondering if it's possible to pass any data to socket client?
What I want to archieve?
I have nodejs + Angular app where I need socket.io functionality. I configured connection and it's working. I'm able to retrieve clientId but I want to pass also username and maybe avatar of logged user so when user is connecting it will show his name nad photo. And behavior should be reversed when user is disconnected.

Does anybody know the way to do it or it's not possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the required data as an object on emit and use it in frontend. Create an object with required key values.

```
var obj= { username:'xyz',avatar:imageUrl };
Socket.on('userConnected',(data)=>{
//do something with data
Socket.emit('userDetails',obj);

}
```